# Physical location (directory) in persistent store for Core data(Objective C)

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-data, nsmanagedobject

I am trying to find out the exact physical location where core data save details in form of managed objects.
I found out the following method implemented in AppDelegate :

```
- (NSURL *)applicationFilesDirectory
{
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSURL *appSupportURL = [[fileManager URLsForDirectory:NSApplicationSupportDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
    return [appSupportURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"testfile"];
}
```

But I could not find any file in the `Application Support` directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just log it.

```
NSLog(@"%@", applicationFilesDirectory);
```

You can then copy the URL from the console and open the directory in the Finder via
<kbd>⌘</kbd>-<kbd>⇧</kbd>-<kbd>G</kbd>.